# eslint not catching misspelled function name defined in another module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have in bob.js:

```
export let say_hello = () => {
    console.log('Hello, I'm Bob!');
};
```

And in main.js:

```
import * as bob from './bob.js';
bob.say_helo();
```

The function call "say_helo()" is obviously misspelled.  I would like eslint to be able to catch such errors, but I seem to be unable to get it to play ball.  Can anybody please tell me what should go in my .eslintrc.js file to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: eslint doesn't know what's in your other files.  As far as I know, it lints one file at a time and can't check imports like that.  You would probably need to use something like TypeScript with actual defined interfaces between modules and a compiler that process them all to get that.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's exactly what I needed.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody else in the future will wonder the same thing, the answer to my problem is to install the plugin eslint-plugin-import.

Comment: Hi there! mind detailing what the rules you set are/your config file? I am having this same issue but as a JS noob, not sure how you were able to utilize `eslint-plugin-import` for this

Answer (score 0):

ESLint runs on one file at a time, and doesn't share data between files. So it's not aware of the function in the other file.